# How to Sync MySQL with python?

Tags: python, mysql, virtual-machine

Im setting a VM.

Both host and VM machine have Mysql. 
How do keep the VM Mysql sync'd to to the host Mysql. 
Host is using MYsql 5.5 on XP.
VM is Mysql 5.1 on Fedora 14.

1) I could DUMP to "shared," Restore. Not sure if this will work.
2) I could network Mysql Host to Mysql VM. Not how to do this

How would I do this with python 2.7?

I dont want them in sync after set-up phase. But, maybe sync some tables or SP occasionly on-rewrites. After I build out Linux Env. I would like to be able to convert V2P and have a dual-boot system.

Comment: What is the goal here. Do you want to keep them in sync as they're running? Or are you trying to back up one of the databases? I don't really see the particular use case here.

Comment: No I dont want them in sync after set-up phase. But, maybe sync some tables or SP occasionly on-rewrites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mysqldump` to make snapshots of the database, and to restore it to known states after tests.

But instead or going into the complication of synchronizing different database instances, it would be best to open the host machine's instance to local network access, and have the applications in the virtual machine access that as if it was a remote server. Overall performance should improve too.

Even if you decide to run different databases for the host and the guest, run then both on the host's MySQL instance. Performance will be better, configuration management will be easier, and the apps in the guest will be tested against a realistic deployment environment.

Comment: On, your VM with remote server...this is not the planned deployment. I want to sync during build-out and and occasionly sync after.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Python?  Just use the built in replication abilities: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html

Comment: I dont want long term (distance) relationships with my MySql databases.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it synced in realtime?

Why not just connect the guest's mysql process to the host?